# How to exclude children categories of parent category

Tags: categories

I want to list only certain categories and exclude a particular parent and all its children. The reason is so that if a new child category is added, it won't show up by default. With wp_list_categories you also get an active class but with get_categories you don't. I would also like to somehow get an active class from it if possible.

I tried this:

```
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'exclude' => array(40)
));
```

But it still shows the children of category with ID 40.

The below code hides all the children but is a pain to try and style it whereas if I run my own loop with get_categories I can style the output much easier.

```
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'show_count' => false,
    'exclude'    => array( 40 )
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'exclude_tree' => array(40)
));
```

In both `get_categories()` and [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) you can use the [`exclude_tree`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) parameter instead of `exclude`.

> - **exclude_tree**
>     (array|string) Array or comma/space-separated string of term ids to exclude along with all of their descendant terms. If *$include* is non-empty, $exclude_tree is ignored.
>     Default empty array.

Comment: Thank you, I also managed to get it working using `'parent' => 0`